# Do we need a "blank" character in Markdown?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

From [this](https://superuser.com/questions/22648/fastest-reliable-way-to-open-the-terminal/22701#22701) question on SU;

Notice the u in chromium isn't *italic*, as it **should** be, given the ***situation***.
However, you can't do *so*meth*in*g like that (although the prettify box says you can), so do we need something like

```
*Ch*romi[blank]*u*[blank]m
```

to allow such a string to be posted?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog this question was asked almost 5 years earlier than that one

Comment: @publicstaticvoidmain This question was asked specifically to address the use-case of intra-word emphasis. This has since been implemented, so this question is no longer relevant. To direct people to the newer one, it's better to close this as a duplicate. Read [our FAQ on duplicate closures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/377214).

Comment: all the things I never knew...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the `<i>` tag: `<i>Ch</i>romi<i>u</i>m` -> *Ch*romi*u*m

---

Ok, if you really want your blank, use a [zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_Width_Space). It's Unicode char 0x200B, and you can use it like this: `Chromi&#x200B;*u*&#x200B;m` -> Chromi​*u*​m

(or, like this... `Chromi​*u*​m` -> Chromi​*u*​m - though this doesn't make a good demo, since by definition the character *doesn't show up*!)

Comment: +1 for solving this problem, but it'd still be nice to have a blk tag, or some such thing.

Answer (score 1):

No.

markdown.pl (the reference implementation of Markdown) supports intra-word-empasis, without the magical blank character you propose:

```
$ echo "Ex*amp*le" | perl markdown.pl
<p>Ex<em>amp</em>le</p>
```

This is disabled in the Stack Overflow version of Markdown, because it's annoying more often than not.. You have a very few cases where you want `my_example_variable` to display as my*example*variable, instead of my_example_variable

If you really want intra-word emphasis, just use the relevant HTML tags as Shog9 suggested:

```
<i>Ch</i>romi<i>u</i>m
```

I really recommend *against* using the Unicode zero-width-space character... The equivalent `&#x200B;` escape sequence seems reasonable, although it's less obvious and harder to read than simply using the HTML tags.

Comment: I realise WHY the inter-word stuff was disabled, and certainly wouldn't want it back, but I've seen blank characters used to great effect in many places - more powerful markup is never a bad thing, right?

Comment: I don't see much benefit for this new bit of syntax.. The cases where you'd need it are pretty obscure, it would further diverging SO's markdown from "the standard", and there is a perfectly good, very readable alternative, which wouldn't require users to remember another bit of syntax (HTML tags, or `&#x200B;`)

Answer (score -1):

I am confused. You say that the `u` **isnt** italic, but this Markdown content:

```
*Ch*romi*u*m
```

**does make it italic**: *Ch*romi*u*m

If you wanted to stop that, you can add a backslash:

```
*Ch*romi\*u*m
```

Result: *Ch*romi*u*m

Comment: "asked Oct 24 '09" — The behavior was changed in 2014 with [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240354/323179)