# Duplicates where the newer question is the more valuable one

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

These two questions: [q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204482/how-to-view-the-source-of-currently-displayed-html-pagedynamically-than-the-ori), [q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750865/best-way-to-view-generated-source-of-webpage) appear to be duplicates. In my opinion, the newer question is better than the older one. How should we handle cases like this?

**Related Questions**

[How to handle duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-to-handle-duplicate-questions)

Comment: Vote to close the older one as a duplicate of the newer one.

Comment: ...and comment to let others know what and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of them should be closed, and point to the other one.  I don't see that it matters which; both can be searched for, and both lead to the answers.  We're not deleting the newer question (I hope), and it remains perfectly searchable.

Comment: Well, if you visit the moderator tools, you will find a steady stream of deletion of duplicates. If the management really wants to keep them, it should make them harder to get rid of. There might be a discussion of some other way to prevent rep-gaming via duplicates if we stop deleting them.

Comment: I've been flagging dupes for moderator attention (to get the answers merged), but I still also vote to delete them (in the general case, but not always). Posts can be merged just as well after deletion as before, so there's no need to wait.