# How to find the duplicate question

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

If a question is closed for being a duplicate, how do you find the duplicate question?

Comment: The duplicate will be linked inside the "closed as duplicate" message.

Comment: Highly related / possible duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a dumb question, as several seem to think.  The great big text warning that the question is a duplicate does **not** hold the link.  You can find the link at the top of the question, next to the up/down arrows for the question.

The link is circled in green.  Your eyes are pulled to where there is not a link, in red.

[image]

Comment: How is this different from the answer posted 4 months ago?

Answer (score 12):

If a question is closed as a duplicate, the respective other question is shown at the top like in this example:

[image: example duplicate question]