# closed as exact duplicate -- how to find the post that it's a duplicate of?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153696/how-to-find-the-duplicate-question)

So I'm using stackoverflow, dutifully doing searches and finding questions that match my search criteria. The problem is, they are closed with a comment, "closed as exact duplicate by ..."

Ok, fine. But where is the question that apparently is preferred? In my opinion, this message should include a link to the original post. It certainly would help folks like me be more productive in searches.

If there is a way to find the duplicate, please explain.

Comment: Give us an example of a post closed as such

Comment: The link to the duplicate _should_ be at the top of the post. If the question is old enough, it was not yet automatically inserted when the question was closed. If it's not too old and the link is missing, somebody edited it out - bad behaviour - then check the revision history of the post. Can you link an example without duplicate link?

Comment: @Daniel, thanks. I never thought to check at the complete opposite end of the post from the message to find the link. Yes, there was one there.