# Comments coming up missing as if deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

I know that on Stack Overflow, a moderator can clear out all comments on posts in one wipe. However, I just noticed that some comments of mine have come up missing, at least 3, which were in no way illegitimate. I'm not asking to recover them or anything, but do moderators (or anyone) have the ability to directly delete one particular comment of another user? If so, shouldn't those people be a bit more responsible and be monitored of such activities? Because it seems that it's only my comments which are disappearing.

For example, [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069691/delphi-what-is-the-way-to-stack-several-bottom-aligned-controls), I had put a comment with a related question link (which in turn wound up to be closed as duplicate with it).

---

**EDIT**

Now I understand it's the system automatically deleting it when it's closed as a duplicate, because the link I had in my comment was identical to the one which was closed. I would have never guessed that. So you mean to say, if I include a bunch of details inside that same comment, it will be automatically deleted too?

I don't seem to think that's fair. But then again, not much of life is fair in the first place.

Comment: And those comments were?

Comment: I'm not looking for revenge or recovery, I just want to know if one can do so, and what they have to accomplish in order to be able to.

Comment: Close as duplicate comments get auto-deleted once the question has been closed as a duplicate (you get a big link at the top no point in a duplicate small one at the bottom anymore). Is this the only type of comment that's going missing? If so your question is a duplicate of the FAQ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled - at the end.

Comment: I see... so it doesn't matter what other types of notes I might include in the comment, the system will automatically delete the whole thing, just because it was a link to the dupe?

Comment: Suppose I put a comment with that link, and type a long explanation with it of something to point out in that other link.

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to call this a bug then? It appears the system detects this just by matching the link, since when someone votes to close as a duplicate, a comment is auto-added with that link. The system confused my comment with the auto-generated one.

Comment: @JerryDodge It's not a bug, it's cleanup. If a comment mentions a duplicate question, it's redundant after the question is closed (because there is then a banner at the top of the question pointing to the duplicate.)  If the question is indeed an exact duplicate of another already answered question, that means that the question has been, in its entirety, answered by that other question's answer; in most cases you shouldn't need to add any other information via comment. If you do, leave a comment on the original question or answer, as that is what will be preserved once the question is closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you posted a link to what ultimately ended up being the duplicate, the system will have nuked that automatically.

Usually that happens to auto-inserted comments that get generated when we vote to close as a duplicate. It might have grabbed yours instead.

Answer (score 4):

> do moderators have the ability to directly delete one particular comment of another user?

Yes.

> [does anyone] have the ability to directly delete one particular comment of another user?

No.  Just mods.

> shouldn't those people be a bit more responsible and be monitored of such activities?

Nope.

Valuable content shouldn't be (just) in comments.  Comments are designed to be temporary.  When posting a comment you should be prepared to have it deleted at any time, for any reason.  If you aren't, then it means that the information belongs somewhere in a question or answer.  The end result of a (good) comment should generally be for a question or answer to be edited to incorporate some additional information.  When that happens, or when it's determined that it won't happen, the comment is no longer needed.