# What's the difference between MathOverflow & Mathematics.SE?

Tags: support, math-se, mathoverflow

If I have a maths question, on which site should I ask: [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) or [Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: As was stated on the previous MathOverflow FAQ: *"MathOverflow's primary goal is for users to ask and answer **research level math questions**, the sorts of questions you come across when you're writing or reading articles or graduate level books."*. I'm sure that in the upcoming days/weeks all the information will be filled out once again.

Comment: @Bart - It is also there on their [about](http://mathoverflow.net/about) page

Comment: @Oded I am only able to find this: `MathOverflow is a question and answer site for mathematicians. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about research level mathematics.`

Comment: @Oded Wow, that took way too many reads to find that. Not at all obvious to find the "research level mathematics" within that (standard?) About page. I glanced over it a couple of times.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - Yes. See that very last bit? `research level mathematics`?

Comment: @Oded Oh yes. After reading multiple times, I was unable to find that. :)

Comment: If you have to ask, math.SE

Comment: Well after reading, it's clear that those 2 sites shouldn't be merged. But these post should be merged with this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/41/differences-between-mathoverflow-and-math-stackexchange or viceversa :)

Comment: While this question is older, I feel like the answer to [What is the intended difference between MathOverflow and Mathematics?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251476/what-is-the-intended-difference-between-mathoverflow-and-mathematics) is better and has more detail, and the general policy for duplicate closures is that the one with the better answers should be the canonical.

Comment: @Sonic What decides "better"? Here, question and answer both have more upvotes. Also, that question survived only because people failed to close it.

Comment: @user178465 See [our FAQ on duplicate closures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled/10844#10844), section *Which question is the duplicate?*, for the relevant policy. The answer to the other question is much more substantive and detailed, containing quotes from the relevant help centers, and links to related questions discussing more context. The answer here simply tersely states which is which.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It depends on the question.

MathOverflow is for research level questions.

Mathematics.SE is for *any* level.

Comment: I will add that more detailed explanation can be found in answers to [Differences between mathoverflow and math.stackexchange.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/41) (Mathematics Meta) and [How is this site different from Mathematics Stack Exchange?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/271) (MathOverflow Meta).