# Does every site that contains "Overflow" mean "for experts"?

Tags: discussion

I just read this this question about [MathOverflow and Mathematics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185784/whats-the-difference-between-mathoverflow-mathematics-se). After reading the answers and comments, I get and idea that every site that contains "Overflow" is meant for experts. MathOverflow is for expert mathematicians, Stack Overflow is for expert programmers, and [Physics Overflow](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/) is for expert physicists. Will someday we will have Health Overflow, Language Overflow (should we change Linguistics to this name?), Hack Overflow (on Area 51), etc?

PS: I know that Physics Overflow doesn't belong to SE

---

As in ChrisF's answer, Server Fault is for expert withou the tag "Overflow". But that's is a legacy site. Maybe starting from now, should we name site for experts like that so that new comers can quickly indicate which site they suit ask.

Comment: Physics Overflow is not an SE site, it's a site which broke off from [physics.se] by a group who wanted to focus on theoretical physics and did not like the civility rules.

Comment: Always take the tour and read the help section to know what the site is about, don't judge sites by their names. It hardly takes a few minutes to take the tour.

Comment: [sticking the word "Overflow" at the end honestly rolls pretty stupid as a name in 90% or more of situations.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5216/renaming-elu-to-englishoverflow?rq=1) -- post by an SE Community Manager.

Comment: New comers *can* quickly identify which site they should be posting on... *if* they read the associated help center page ([mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic), [math](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and so forth). This is also mentioned in the associated tour pages ([academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/tour), [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)) that new users see.

Comment: @Manishearth PhysicsOverflow has been started outside SE to not have to fullfill externally prescribed activity criteria, such as Area51 statistics for example. Also building up a small (in the context of SE standards) rather closed high-level academic community generally poorly fits into the SE model. See for example [this](http://nforum.mathforge.org/discussion/3192/theoretical-physics-stackexchange/) discussion among former TP.SE members where they consider it to have been a mistake to start the Theoretical Physics site inside the SE network.

Comment: The targetted audience of PhysicsOverflow is advanced students and "grown up" physicists, so we dont have to patronize our members and constantly tell them how they are allowed to talk to each other etc ... So we focus on the physics instead of putting up a large bureaucratic overhead of niceness rules, codes of conduct, and similar things. However, this does not mean that there is a wilde horde ravaging on PhysicsOverflow ;-), as unprofessional people who are for some reasons interested in misrepresenting the site often forcefully insinuate ...

Answer (score 12):

From the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page on Stack Overflow.

> **Stack Overflow** is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers

From the [tour](https://serverfault.com/tour) page on Server Fault:

> **Server Fault** is a question and answer site for [professional system and network administrators](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity)

So, no just because a site has "Overflow" in it's name doesn't mean it's for experts - and vice versa.

In addition it shouldn't have that meaning. That would make the naming of new sites even harder.

Comment: but should it? I mean like an indicator for new comers to easily know which site is suitable for the questions.

Comment: @Ooker - no it shouldn't

Comment: why does it make the naming the new sites even harder? Just "X + Overflow"

Comment: Many sites are professional based

Comment: @Ooker - In general "X + Overflow" would be a crap name for a site.

Comment: and some would be a mouthful.... e.g. Mathematics Educators Overflow.... History of Science and Mathematics Overflow...

Comment: @ChrisF: Then Math Overflow and Hack Overflow (in Area 51) will be crap names. Or Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Gone: yeah, lone names might be bad.

Comment: @Ooker, coincidentally ChrisF is an elected moderator on the site that that you think has a crap name - Stack Overflow

Comment: @Ooker let me guess, you are [not a programmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow "for programmers, 'stack overflow' in the site name denotes smart play of words") (unlike [Infinite Recursion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/245167/infinite-recursion):)