# Trade-off for a research-level math question: larger society of Math.SE or more powerful society of MathOverflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, math-se, mathoverflow

Sometimes I have some research-level mathematics questions; as I have read in "[What's the difference between MathOverflow & Mathematics.SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185784/whats-the-difference-between-mathoverflow-mathematics-se)" and similar questions, I know that I can post on both the Math.SE and MathOverflow societies. But there is a trade-off; the former has a larger society and also in theory has lots of users in common with the latter, which I can user hints of all of them.

But in the latter, I suppose, the users are all the ones who are prepared for such research games. Which one do you suggest in this trade-off?

My own choice, up to now, is to use MathOverflow, in which the users' business is research, because I think that even the users of both sites, when they are on Math.SE, are not searching for research as serious as what they do on MathOverflow.

Comment: If you fail to find some other criterion for your decision: On Math.SE, you have sufficient reputation to place bounties.

Comment: Suppose that I would earn also the enough score for bounty in the MO; then which one do you suggest?

Comment: I am not sufficiently familiar with those communities to make a suggestion. That’s why I started with “If you fail to find some other criterion for your decision”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the former has a larger society

Let's look at this more carefully.

[image: comparison]

- The number of users is 4 times greater on Math.SE. Potentially, more people to look at your question.
- However,  more relevant is the number of potential answerers. There are 19165 users with *Teacher badge* on Math, vs 7923 on MO. The ratio is about 2.4.
- The number of questions per day is 17 times greater on Math.SE.  This outweighs the preceding point by a decent factor. There are 7 times fewer answerers per question on Math.

The ratio of answered questions is about the same, but this hides the disparity by level of question. On MO, this is the ratio for research-level questions; on Math, for all questions, including a very large number of basic calculus and probability questions.

Conclusion: with research-level questions, go to MO.

That said... on Math.SE your question has a chance to be tweeted!

Answer (score 4):

This decision is yours to make; however, having said that, one way to gauge your confidence in which site to post your questions is to:

- Read each site's Help Centre and Tour pages
- Search for similar topics relevant to your area of research (who knows, you may find some answers are already there!)
- Read the questions and answers for those topics to see the level and quality of responses.

And base your decision on that.