# What is the intended difference between MathOverflow and Mathematics?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, math-se, mathoverflow

There really does need to be some descriptions here. The two sites seem so similar that I'm unsure which is the proper one to use for certain math issues. In what situations would you use [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) over [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Did you read the tour page of each? It is rather clear what the difference is.

Comment: And if you want to have a more detailed discussion on the topic (beyond what's in the help center), you'll be able to find more information on the subject on either site's meta, rather than here.

Comment: You could also read some of their questions to get the general feeling of each site.

Comment: For those voting to close because "pertains only to a specific site", can I ask which one of *the two* (MathOverflow and Mathematics) it specifically pertains to?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the help centers of both sites:

[MathOverflow help center:](https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic)

> MathOverflow's primary goal is for users to ask and answer **research level<sup>(1)</sup> math questions**, the sorts of questions you come across when you're writing or reading articles or graduate level books.

[Math.SE help center:](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> **Mathematics Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields

For more information see these posts,

- [Differences between mathoverflow and math.stackexchange.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/differences-between-mathoverflow-and-math-stackexchange)
- [How to decide whether a soft/history question belongs to MSE or Mathoverflow](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12550/how-to-decide-whether-a-soft-history-question-belongs-to-mse-or-mathoverflow)
- [Why is "what is the difference between mathoverflow and math.stackexchange?" not prominently displayed?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2142/why-is-what-is-the-difference-between-mathoverflow-and-math-stackexchange-not/2143#2143)
- [Description of what kinds of questions are appropriate](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/10/description-of-what-kinds-of-questions-are-appropriate/36#36)
- <sup>(1)</sup>[What does research-level mathematics mean?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1024/what-does-research-level-mathematics-mean)

Answer (score 12):

[Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) is for **[students of mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)**, and for professionals in related fields, e.g. statisticians, quantitative finance analysts.

Questions about problems in a mathematics course or textbook, and about understanding math concepts are appropriate.

Questions about software used by mathematicians are also on topic (with the exception of Mathematica because there is already a Stack Exchange site devoted to that, Mathematica SE). Questions about solving math puzzles are welcomed.

In contrast, [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net) is for **[professional mathematicians](https://mathoverflow.net/tour)**, mathematics graduate students, and undergraduates involved in research.

- Math Overflow's [primary goal](https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic):

> is for users to ask and answer mathematical questions related to current
> research in mathematics... [also] questions when reading scholarly journals
> or advanced graduate level books in mathematics.
>
> MathOverflow is not for homework help.

If you aren't sure whether a question belongs on Math Stack Exchange or Math Overflow, or somewhere else on (or off) the Stack Exchange network, this [Math Overflow meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/3761/15938) answer should be helpful. It lists several related SE and non-SE Q&A websites.

Comment: Better than the accepted answer, you're not just quoting from help centers.