# Replace Stack Exchange logo by site's logo in the top bar

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

One of the complaints I have seen about the new design is that it is more uniform that it used be and often it is difficult to distinguish sites from another.<sup>1</sup> (Especially if you are viewing a question and scroll down.)

**Proposal:** Instead of Stack Exchange logo in the top-bar on the left, use a logo of the site.

This would add at least one more element which can help to distinguish various sites. Moreover, top bar stays there even if you scroll down.

When I tried to switch to mobile web, I saw that in mobile web site's name is already displayed in that place. Although in mobile web the top bar disappears when you scroll down (unlike in desktop version).

---

<sup>1</sup>I will admit that the only discussion related to redesign that I followed really closely was on MathOverflow (see: [How can we visually differentiate MathOverflow from MathStackExchange within the constraints of the new design themes?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4004)) But it would not be a surprise if the same problem appeared on other sites. (Similarly as [MathOverflow and Mathematics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185784/whats-the-difference-between-mathoverflow-mathematics-se), this is more of a problem if there are two sites with rather similar or overlapping scopes.)

Comment: I'm neutral about this request, but it would undoubtedly solve a problem: it's common for websites to provide a single-click link to their home in the top left corner, and SE sites lack this at the moment

Comment: @NicolaSap IIRC something like that used to be on the left, but it was moved to the right during the redesign in 2017: [New top bar is live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301845).

Comment: Yes but it's now two-click to home

Comment: @NicolaSap I'm also neutral about this but there is a conflict of interest here. While users might think this site is their "home", it is part of a larger network of sites, which you could consider its 'home". The company needs the traffic to keep all these sites going, so some screen real-estate has to be offered to make that happen.  In the initial roll-out the stack exchange logo wasn't clickable at all, so at least that improved.

Comment: @rene I actually realised after commenting that the first link on the sidebar is "Home", is persistent, and appears on the top-left. Enough for me to just go with it. Maybe it could be styled -- to address the problem of site recognisability -- but I'm no graphic designer and I wouldn't know how to avoid it being an eyesore

Comment: Note that the sticky top bar is actually a preference. Go to https://mathoverflow.net/users/edit/current, then ***Preferences***, and you will see it.