# What should the help link be for asking about questions already answered?

Tags: support, help-center

When I go to [Meta Stack Exchange / help / how-to-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) there's a link to search in the bulleted list on this and other sites.

> ...have **already been asked** and answered many times before.

Comment: I think it should link to a page that describes how to link to other questions in answers and some etiquette.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Telling users to not answer known duplicates is important. Garbage breeds garbage. Same reason why answering very low quality and other off-topic questions (e.g., tool recommendation requests on Stack Overflow) should be discouraged.

I do, however, think the text in the help center should be annotated with something along the lines of the following:

> (Please [flag it as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) instead.)

Comment: +1 but I think the link should instead go to [How should duplicate questions be handled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ [tag:status-completed]