# How can I alleviate downvotes on a closed, but answered question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, down-votes, closed-questions, deleted-questions

OK, so let me explain this question with an example.

I ask a really stupid question that's either duplicate or too broad or something else.

Someone answers my question, and the first line of the answer says that it's too broad / duplicate.

Many people vote to close the question. I understand that this question is useless and I decide to delete it.

ERROR: People have spent their time answering... so you can't delete this question.

So then I say okay, fair enough. Then 2 - 3 people downvote me, telling me that the question is useless. Now every time someone starts typing a question similar to mine, they see:

> Questions That may already have your answer -
>
> 1. The Stupid Question [DUPLICATE]

So then they check the question out, leave me a downvote, and go back.

This way I keep getting downvotes and unless someone leaves delete votes, there is no way I can stop getting downvotes!

Comment: This is more of the fault of the users who answered. In general, users shouldn't answer questions that are likely to be closed.

Comment: yeah... fun aint it? I wish people would stop answering questions that should be deleted. but, alas, they're "just trying to help!"

Comment: @KevinB In the process of trying to be welcoming, it's actually being incredibly unwelcoming once the user runs into the curation process, for these exact reasons.  Can't see the forest for the trees.

Comment: Would you like it better if we call it _Karma_?

Comment: I've tried re-titling this to be a bit more in line with what the question seems to be asking.  That may help with the downvotes here, anyways.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case, you should flag for moderator attention and ask for your question to be deleted.

Users shouldn't be answering questions that are likely to be closed, and it looks like you got caught in an unfortunate trap because someone did.

It's likely that the moderator will proceed with the deletion, since the question isn't really suitable for the site or helpful to other users. Be sure to clearly explain the situation in your flag, like you did here.

Comment: @KhushrajRathod I disagree that this is a duplicate. So far, only one user has cast a close vote (which you can't see since you have less than 250 rep). According to our [official guidance on duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/), you can answer a question if you don't believe it's a duplicate. Also, here on Meta Stack Exchange, [people vote based on whether or not they agree or disagree with the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47635/377214), which is different on main Q&A sites.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog - Yet this question was indeed closed as being of a duplicate of two different questions.

Comment: @Ramhound Note that when I posted the above comment, there was a different proposed target, and I disagreed that it was a dupe of *that* target.