# Permanent deletion, perhaps

Tags: feature-request, visibility

Do we have a way to permanently delete posts? My mobile browser accidentally submitted a half-answer on [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/166760/44805) question, and in a fit of idiocy I wrote another answer from scratch and 'deleted' the old one. I'd love it if the answer were *actually* deleted, as it contains basically no value, rather than hidden. Is this a thing we do, or should do? Will the garbage collector come and delete it on its own?

Comment: Most people can't see it, so I'm not really sure what the problem is.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog In this case though he can still see his answer because he's the author, not because he's a 10k'er. I believe you already knew this, but I'm commenting so that the OP knows why he still sees his so called "worthless" answer.

Comment: @Laf-ReinstateMonica While that question asks specifically about 10k+ users, the answer there is applicable here: it explains why they're merely hidden. Per the [policy on duplicate closures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/377214) (see the last section), this can be closed, as that question answers this one, and feature requests that go against an SE principle can be closed as duplicates of questions that explain that principle.

Comment: *Do we have a way to permanently delete posts?* No. *Is this a thing we do, or should do?* No, if it bothers you you could make an edit to that deleted answer to say "posted in error, please disregard" to prevent a 10K-er or mod decides to undelete it later.  *Will the garbage collector come and delete it on its own?.* No, everything on SE is soft deleted, with probably the only exception your PII if you delete your account

Comment: Hey, I was in the same boat as you - I double-posted an answer once. Even when I deleted the duplicate one, it was I could still see it and it stretched the page. My "solution" was to edit it and replace the entire body with `-- double posted an answer by accident ---`. So it still exists but at least doesn't take up as much space.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I know, and I agree with you that it is applicable here indeed. I was not questioning whether closing this question as duplicate was a good thing or not, I only wanted to let the OP know that his specific case was slightly different than the question you linked to, but that the same principle applied. I assumed he didn't know it would, since he might not be fully aware of how SE works.