# A duplicated question with bad writing and bad tagging but better answers

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

The first question was asked, with all possible tags, but received no long answers.

A few months later, the second question was asked without address the first one. The second was poorly worded with poor tags. However, the second one received long answers.

**Which one shall be closed, if any?**

When I ask any question, I always spend a long time researching similar questions, looking for any duplications. If there are any duplication, I won't ask my question.

However, I believe that the second question shall not be closed after it received many good answers; it might be tagged in the first place when it was asked.

Comment: Per the first duplicate target above (the FAQ on duplicates): *If one question has great answers but bad wording, and the other has poor or no answers but great wording, edit the badly-worded question and close the other one as a duplicate.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators have an option to Merge whole Q/A.

You can flag the second question and ask to have the answers merged into the first question.

That way the best content is curated and that will help the many visitors still to come.

From the [FAQ on How Should duplicate questions be handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled#should-i-flag-for-moderator-attention):

> **Merging:** Moderators can merge duplicate questions, which moves all of the answers to the same question. This only works if the questions have identical or very similar wording. If you think two questions should be merged, check whether the answers as worded would make perfect sense on the other question. If they do, first follow the above instructions and wait until the post is closed as a duplicate, then once it is, flag the duplicate for moderator attention and explain why you think the merge would be a good idea.