# Bug with extended discussions?

Tags: bug, comments

When there were too many comments, I received this message:

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

I clicked the link, and went back to the question, but the message was still there! Isn't it supposed to be removed after clicking it?

I refreshed the page multiple times and it stayed there.

[image]

Link: [Move two matches so that no triangle remains](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116764/move-two-matches-so-that-no-triangle-remains/)

Comment: [Duplicates on meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-does-duplicate-closing-work-when-is-a-question-a-duplicate-and-how-should#:~:text=on%20the%20site.-,Do%20duplicate%20closures%20work%20differently%20on%20meta%20sites%3F,-Duplicate%20closures%20work) work differently. The bug report is the same. You can clarify in the comments there (or post a new answer), that refreshing or rebooting doesn't work. But I guess they did reload the page once (it disappeared, but came back again).

Comment: Provided you're adding something new to the table, answering that question is fine. You can post a *comment* if there's nothing new to add or if you want to clarify something.