# Allow suggesting more than one duplicate

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Often after voting to close a question as a duplicate, you come across some other original that is even better, and more fitting. Sometimes, even more than one.

However, you can't suggest that one any more. The only option left to you is to manually add it as a comment. However,

- a manually added comment will never make it into the "possible duplicates" section that gets auto-pasted into the question head when it gets closed
- the comment's link won't be automatically turned into a fancy one with the question title.

I suggest allowing users to **suggest** as many duplicates as they like, while of course only the first suggestion counts as an actual **vote**.

Except for not counting as a vote, the additional suggestions would be first-class citizens in that:

- they get an auto-inserted `possible duplicate of` comment
- they are shown in the "other users suggested these ...." list when voting to close as a dupe
- they are auto-inserted into the grey "duplicates" box when the question gets closed

Comment: Also very useful if the first duplicate is not a duplicate after all, for example after the question asker has clarified a bit more. (Or when one simply was not reading too well...)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/allow-same-user-to-add-multiple-links-as-possible-duplicates

Comment: @Tim good find!

Comment: Achievement unlocked: irony

Comment: @status not yet! Needs a second duplicate link first.

Comment: Here you go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92360/can-we-improve-the-ui-for-suggesting-multiple-duplicates (is being closed as a duplicate of this and the post that this is a duplicate of... and another one, if I can find one)