# Can we improve the UI for suggesting multiple duplicates?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Allow same user to add multiple links as possible duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/allow-same-user-to-add-multiple-links-as-possible-duplicates)
>   [Allow suggesting more than one duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88586/allow-suggesting-more-than-one-duplicate)

When I vote to close a question as a duplicate, I often find more than one that is a duplicate candidate. Can there be a sophisticated way of handling such cases? There may be a few ways; I am not sure what is the best.

For example, can I be allowed to enter in multiple duplicate candidates when voting? Each time someone adds a duplicate candidate, a checkbox with a number of votes will be shown next to it so that a later person to vote can check the boxes or add some more candidates.

I would also like to suggest a feature like this: If question C is closed as duplicate of  questions A and B, and neither A nor B is closed as duplicate of one another, then the newer one among A or B will also be closed as duplicate of the other.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Ironical.

Comment: It quite is. I could have listed more questions as duplicate, but at the end the other questions would be duplicate of the question I linked in my previous comment. `:-)`

Comment: If two more people vote to close this post, you will see that the system does support displaying up to five other duplicate questions (if each close voter chooses a different duplicate). Yes, I realize this isn't what you're asking for; just pointing it out.