# Flagging a multipart question with multiple duplicates

Tags: support, flags, flag-dialog

I know that the issue of flagging a question that has more than one duplicate has been [brought up before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/allow-same-user-to-add-multiple-links-as-possible-duplicates), but what is the protocol for flagging a multipart question where each part has its own duplicate?

So say if a question is comprised of a section of `"We want more meta"` and a second section of `"Down with downvotes"`, and `"We want more meta"` is a duplicate of `post A`, and `"Down with downvotes"` is a duplicate of `post B`

I'm hesitant to just paste the link to `post A` into the flag as duplicate dialog, as technically it's not a duplicate of both halves of the question.  Would a flag including post A, along with a comment indicating both post A and post B were duplicates be sufficient?

(just to clarify, this is definitely not an implied feature request to be able to enter multiple duplicates, just a question of protocol)

Comment: [You should stop worrying and love dupes.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: @Won't I can't at all disagree with the philosophy behind it, but when it comes to the nitty-gritty of where to draw the line, it's more of a mire.  How many times do you truly want to see another "Plz make coments on downvotes" question roll through?  Plus, you've seen `Dr. Strangelove`, you know how it all works out :)

Comment: It works out pretty awesomely.  YEEEEEHAAAAW!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case is it not an exact duplicate and I would not vote to close it as an exact duplicate.  However, the question might still need to be closed as "Not a real question", since it is too broad.  I would at least post a link to the question in a comment and mention something to the OP.  Ideally, they could use post A to answer their first question and edit their post to just contains their second question.

Comment: I see what you are saying about the NaRQ possibility.  I think if you can't close duplicates by "superposition" like this, it opens up the possibility for you to reask the exact same questions as long as they were combined with other questions.

Comment: @jonsca, well as I mentioned, if you are asking multiple duplicates, it should be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen, but it doesn't seem to be a broad practice, the question closed as a duplicate of post A, then a link to post B is manually added to the "Possible duplicate" text.

Comment: I like this idea a lot.  I've seen that in situations where there may have been multiple votes to close each with a different question specified.  That makes sense to me, but as @jzd has brought up, a question can't likely be an "exact" duplicate of multiple questions.  I feel like it becomes more cut and dried when I can just vote, but that will have to wait :)